# How is this called? Menu moving with scrollbar

Tags: website-design

How is it called when the menu with all the links at the top of a website is "moving" when you scroll down to read more?

And if we are on it: how is the "moving" sidebar called with twitter, facebook ect buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is also referred to as [fixed navigation](https://speckyboy.com/30-fantastic-examples-fixed-navigation-menus-web-design/) or fixed menu.

Comment: I voted this answer as the most helpful, because you also gave reference edits to the others. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap refers to this as [Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix).

Answer (score 0):

It's called a ["sticky](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/topbar.html#sticky-top-bar) [menu](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/09/sticky-menus-are-quicker-to-navigate/)", or "sticky navigation".